# How to pass start time option to PyAV

Tags: python, pyav

I am trying to read an audio file starting at a particular time in second. In FFMPEG you would put `-ss x` to do this.

In this project, I am using PyAv 10. [Per the documentation](https://pyav.org/docs/stable/api/_globals.html) the open function has `options`. But I can't find nowhere what options can be passed.

I assumed it's straight FFMPEG options but it does not seem to work.

So I am trying to figure out a) what options can be passed to `PyAv.open` function but more importantly, how to get the audio starting from a particulart point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You want to ***seek*** in the file.

That is not an option of `open()`.

Examples can be found in the PyAV code base: https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/tests/test_seek.py